# No applicable approval process was found (Works in Debug mode)

Tags: community, visual-workflow, permissions, approval-process, experience-cloud

Spent the whole day trying to find out what is the problem but didn't succeed.

**Setup:** An org with an Experience Cloud i.e. Community website.
The website has a custom registration process which is implemented by the use of a Flow (Community_Self_Reg_Contact)
The flow asks for new user's data, checks for existing Contact and Lead and if there are no records with the specified by the use email, creates a new Lead and if there are no already awaiting Approval Requests, submits it to the approval process (Self-Reg Approval Lead).

Here is how the approval process looks like:
[image]

**Problem:** Everything works as expected when I click on Debug in Flow Builder and test, but if I go through the registration process using the same flow from the Experience Cloud website as a guest user, the flow fails giving me this log:

```
Error element New_Lead (FlowRecordCreate).
This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the “Send Lead for Approval” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. No applicable approval process was found. Error ID: 308525548-113247 (394671088)No applicable approval process was found. Error ID: 308525548-113247 (394671088). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
Flow Details
Flow API Name: Community_Self_Reg_Contact
Type: Screen Flow
Version: 34
Status: Active
Org: XXXX (XXXXXXXXXXXX)

Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: Community Self-Reg Contact 7/14/2021, 3:51 PM Contact - Lead - entDateTime}
Current User: XXXX Site Guest User (0054W00000DAQqX)
Start time: 7/14/2021, 3:51 PM
Duration: 9 seconds
How the Interview Started
XXXX Site Guest User (0054W00000DAQqX) started the flow interview.
API Version for Running the Flow: 51
Transaction Committed
Any records that the flow was ready to create, update, or delete were committed to the database.
SCREEN: Inquire_Membership
Display Text: first_screen
Value at run time:

Welcome to the XXXX Member Site!

If you want to become a part of our community, fill in the form!



Lightning Component: new_contact_form
Screen component: flowruntime:name
Inputs:
Outputs:
fieldsToDisplayList = firstName,lastName
firstName = asdfsd
label = Name
lastName = fsdf
salutationOptions = Mr.,Mrs.,Ms.

Textbox: new_contact_title
Label: Title
Value at run time: sdfsdf

Textbox: Company_Name
Label: Company Name
Value at run time: sdf

Lightning Component: new_contact_email
Screen component: flowruntime:email
Inputs:
Outputs:
disabled = false
label = Email
placeholder = you@example.com
readonly = false
required = false
value = movs@asdasd.com

Selected Navigation Button: NEXT
GET RECORDS: Check_existing_contacts_for_same_email
Find all Contact records where:
Email Equals {!new_contact_email.value} (movs@asdasd.com)
OR Secondary_Email__c Equals {!new_contact_email.value} (movs@asdasd.com)
Store the values of these fields in Check_existing_contacts_for_same_email: Id
Result
Failed to find records.

GET RECORDS: Find_Approval_Request_for_Contact
Find all ProcessInstance records where:
TargetObjectId Equals {!Check_existing_contacts_for_same_email.Id} (null)
AND Status Equals Pending
Store the values of these fields in Find_Approval_Request_for_Contact: Id
Result
Failed to find records.
GET RECORDS: Check_existing_lead
Find all Lead records where:
Email Equals {!new_contact_email.value} (movs@asdasd.com)

Company = {!Company_Name} (sdf)
Email = {!new_contact_email.value} (movs@asdasd.com)
FirstName = {!new_contact_form.firstName} (asdfsd)
LastName = {!new_contact_form.lastName} (fsdf)
OwnerId = {!$User.Id} (0054W00000DAQqX)
Title = {!new_contact_title} (sdfsdf)
Result
Failed to create record.
Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the “Send Lead for Approval” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. No applicable approval process was found. Error ID: 308525548-113247 (394671088)No applicable approval process was found. Error ID: 308525548-113247 (394671088). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the
```

**Need some suggestions on what could be causing this behavior**.

I thought it might be because of Initial Submitters but even if I set explicitly OwnerId and SubmitterId to be the same $User.Id that doesn't change anything. I also thought about permissions but didn't find anything pertaining to approval processes for the Community Guest User Profile - it has access to create Leads and Contacts though.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when a Guest User executes the flow, records created by it are assigned (OwnerId=) to some random users from CRM instead of that Guest User, this is because from recent editions SF doesn't allow Guest Users to own records, and when the flow submits that record for approval its SubmitterId is Guest User Id (or something else), anyways, those two should be the same, and I ended up looking up for OwnerId of the record to be submitted and putting it explicitly in SubmitterId, now it works.